# How to format php Datetime?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, format

I am using this code to show last date of the month

```
<?php
    $day=new DateTime('last day of this month'); 
    echo $day->format('M jS');
?>
```

but its giving output as "Feb 28th"

I want output as "February 28th, 2017"

How do I achieve it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Google can tell you much more! you should read the manual and do some research & practice  that's how you learn!

Comment: [Everything you need is right here in the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), under the format section. Good luck!

Comment: How did you write this code? This is an extremely simple thing to solve that would have taken you a few seconds.    Please grab a copy of the PHP docs, or at least bookmark them. http://php.net/docs.php ` M jS Y`

Comment: Hi Duane, 

'M jS Y' did not give the proper output it gave "02" instead name of the month so the right answer is 'F jS, Y'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php.net has great, understandable, documentation on every function. I really suggest reading it  [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), that is how I learned php. The format you're looking for is this:

`echo $day->format('F jS, Y');`

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

This code outputs what you want.

```
echo date("F tS, Y",time());
```

Comment: Hi Rolling, It gives right answer except with February 28. Instead of February 28th it gives February 28nd. Apart from this it gives exact output. thanks